# Which red and green colors look still different when printed as grayscale?

Tags: color, color-conversion

I'm looking for red and green colors which are still really distinct when printed as a grayscale image.
My current color values (224,133,0 and 168,181,10) are really industuingable on paper.

Comment: If they are indistinguishable, then try varying them and see how they come out. Just use photoshop's desaturate filter once in a while to get an idea of how they will look.

Answer (score 3):

Any variation in brightness/saturation of colors will be distinguishable in greyscale. I.E. a bright red and a darker green. Or a dark red/burgundy and a bright green.

[image]

But really the best red green in greyscale is this one....

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, do you happen know any good RGB values?

Comment: You seriously need *me* to decide exactly what red and exactly what green for you? I can't do that without knowing *much* more about the project in general.

Comment: Haha, yes I'm super lazy and the exact colors don't matter much. I will use the colors from your example image. BTW, I'm a programmer, the graphics guy came up with the current colors...